# How to get name of rendered temlpate in rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I get the name of the rendered template in rails 3.2.8?

Notes:

1) This has to work if the action renders with `:template` or `:action`

2) The following doesn't work in 3.2.8:  `<%= self._template.identifier %>`

3) This has to work -- giving the correct result -- when being called from within the layout.

Answer (score 0):

i am using slim, but i think that this would work the same way in erb...

```
= __FILE__
```

Comment: That violates #3:  it prints `.../app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

Comment: so you get ```app/views/layouts/application.html.erb``` as output even though you put that into a partial?

Comment: Sorry for not providing more details.  I get that when putting it in the layout.  It's "being called from within the layout".

This is possible to do if you use `ActiveSupport::Notifications` to subscribe to `!render_template.action_vew` and append.  The template gets called before the layout, so you should have a list of just the one template.  As the layout gets notified after.

I didn't really like that approach, though it's probably the only one.  I just define @page_template at the top of each template now to be safe.